# Create list with triangles on the right side CSS

Tags: css, html-lists, css-shapes

Im trying to create a list like on the image, but I cant figure out how to do it. So far I've done this, but seems im not doing it right:

My work so far:

```
#side-menu li:nth-child(even) {
background: rgb(0,169,148);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,169,148,1) 1%, rgba(0,84,166,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(1%,rgba(0,169,148,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,84,166,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,169,148,1) 1%,rgba(0,84,166,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,169,148,1) 1%,rgba(0,84,166,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,169,148,1) 1%,rgba(0,84,166,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,169,148,1) 1%,rgba(0,84,166,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00a994', endColorstr='#0054a6',GradientType=1 );
border-top: 13px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
border-left: 10px solid rgba(0,84,166,1);
}
```

and current looks:

[image]

and how it should be:

[image]

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: @Ravimallya i think this will be the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this problem. Since you started with CSS3 already, [here's my approach using CSS only](http://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/W9yAD/).

What's done here is essentially abusing the borders around an empty HTML element. By not setting the right border it's set to 0. The other borders are then adjusted to fit the borders, which happens to result in an arrow shape being created.

Due to this, modifying the size/shape of the arrow can be a bit tricky (there are multiple options; I prefer this for the current situation):

- Set a line height for the `<li>` so it's easier to determine the correct arrow height.
- To adjust the arrow size, you'll have to set `li:after`'s width of both, `border-top` and `border-bottom` to 50% of the value `line-height + padding-top + padding-bottom` of the `<li>` element..
- By adjusting `border-left` you're able to determine the length of the arrow.
- Finally, `margin-top` of `li + li` will define the spacing between the arrows.

Since your image also suggests some hover color, that's possible as well as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/W9yAD/2/). Although it's important to note that transitions won't work for gradients so far.

Of course, using a fixed image as the background would be even more backwards compatible with older browsers, but this also really depends

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://cssarrowplease.com/ website to create custom arrows in all directions. Change the height to whatever you needed. You can then tweak the styles to get exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it:

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SM2NR/

```
#side-menu li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: -13px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #0054A6;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
}
```